# Slideshow isn't displayed properly in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, animation, joomla

http://askanier.square7.ch/
When the slide animations starts, you'll see that the next image isn't loaded instantly. Also, when loading the page, the loading icon of the slideshow is not in the center. These things happens in Chrome only, why?

Comment: Have you tried contacting the developer of the slideshow module?

Comment: not yet. i dont think its necessarily because of the slideshow module.

Comment: It is necessary because it works on Firefox but not Chrome, thus the issue could be a possible bug with the module, in which case the developer should be contacted. I checked the console log and there appears to be an error but don't think it's related.

Comment: right. the error isn't related.